# pointer to std::map fails to insert

Tags: c++, stdmap

I am very confused. Why does this work:

```
double doubleValue = 20;
NcVar variable = {some process obtaining an instance}
map<NcVar,double> th;
th.insert(std::make_pair(variable, doubleValue));
```

and this fails:

```
double doubleValue = 20;
NcVar variable = {some process obtaining an instance}
map<NcVar,double> *th = new map<NcVar,double>();
th->insert(std::make_pair(variable, doubleValue));
```

That means, the first variant ends up with one key/value-pair, while the second leaves the map unchanged (0 entries)?

Comment: How do you know that it fails?  There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted here, so I assume the error is elsewhere.

Comment: You will get better help if you post a complete program and describe what behavior you expect and what behavior you observe.

Comment: I know it fails because in the first case the map has an entry. In the second code it winds up empty. I do check this in the debugger. The rest of the code is really of no consequence, just parsing some command line parameters. Nothing spectacular.

Comment: Yes, it is std::map. I am using boost (among other things), but that should not interfere with std::map afaik.

Comment: If you are so sure it fails, post some simple code that shows this. It is hard to see how it could be possible.

Comment: 'Works for me' http://ideone.com/3P1mUA

Comment: Does not work for me. I extirpated the code from the larger program it was embedded in into a standalone. Same trouble. See here: http://ideone.com/XiAetN

PS: you will not be able to run this without a NetCDF-File that is CF-Metadata compliant. This is why I was trying to avoid posting it here.

Comment: What fails? run-time erro?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  typedef map<int,float> mapp;
  mapp map1;
  map1.insert(make_pair(1,1.1));

  mapp * mp2 = new mapp();
  mp2->insert(make_pair(2,2.2));
  cout << map1.begin()->second << endl;
  cout << mp2->begin()->second <<endl;
return 0;

}
```

And output:

```
$g++ map_test.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
1.1
2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, guys. I feel kinda stupid now. The assumption that the map was empty was based on the appearance in the debugger. I am using XCode as IDE and when using a pointer to map, it would simply mess up and display the map as empty. Using cout revealed the truth.